# opening a text file with excel opentext file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to open a txt file with excel

which is like a "csv" file but instead of a comma,
I want to use another character like start (`*`) after opening I would like to save it as an xlsx file
how can I do that with the function `Workbooks.opentext()`?

can you please give me a code example

this is the code I am using  however I am getting an error since I am not sure how to use the openText method character

```
  xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
  var _wbs = xlApp.Workbooks;
 _wbs.OpenText(pathTemp,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.oy //0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, '^');
 _wbs[0].SaveAs(pathTemp + "Barak.xlsx");
```

Comment: When I want to know how to do something with Excel using code, I prefer to start recording a new macro and doing in the UI what I want to achieve programatically. Once done, I just open the recorded macro and adapt the vb code to .net.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you be specific about it? Is it a compile error? Or do you get the error while running your code?

Comment: Excel only knows how to do a comma, tab and space deliminated files. Access may be able to be used as a go between because you can select the deliminator there; then export the data to the workbook you want.

Comment: @AxGryndr that is not true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097%28v=office.15%29.aspx see other and otherchar

Comment: My mistake Excel can only export that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
_wbs.OpenText(Path:=pathTemp,Datatype:=xlDelimited,Other:=True,Otherchar:="*");
```

Comment: Hן I think this is the answer however, I think I missing a "using" since it doesn't recognize the path, datatype,other and otherchart do you know which "using" I need to use?

Comment: Hן I used. this code but it igonres that divide by '^' file
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application xlAppResult = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var _wbs = xlAppResult.Workbooks;                
_wbs.OpenText(Filename: pathTemp,  Other:true , OtherChar: '^');